# Chrome crashes after several hours while multiprocessing using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, multiprocessing, selenium-chromedriver

This is the error traceback after several hours of scraping:

```
The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.
```

This is my setup of selenium python:

```
#scrape.py
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def run_scrape(link):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36")
    chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
    browser.get(<link passed here>)
    try:
        #scrape process
    except:
        #other stuffs
    browser.quit()
```

```
#multiprocess.py
import time,
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scrape import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    #links = list of links to be scraped
    pool = Pool(20)
    results = pool.map(run_scrape, links)
    pool.close()
    print("Total Time Processed: "+"--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Chrome, ChromeDriver Setup, Selenium Version

```
ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614})
Google Chrome 79.0.3945.79
Selenium Version: 4.0.0a3
```

Im wondering why is the chrome is closing but other processes are working?

Comment: how to check binary version of chrome and chromedriver? and i need to run in headless mode since it will be run in linux server

Comment: I have set up your code and it's working fine in local. are you facing issue in docker?

Comment: i haven't used docker, its just selenium python, chrome, and chromedriver

Comment: might help https://chromedriver.chromium.org/help/chrome-doesn-t-start

Comment: Already tried, as you can see im passing --no-sandbox in the add_argument, i just dont know why chrome crashes

Comment: yes, it is working fine for me.I'm using the chrome driver version and browser version as you are using.

Comment: for instance of this, can i revive the chrome in the same chromedriver if it crashes?

Comment: you can do it. but it will take more time. check all structure because the same code it is working.

Comment: how would i do it? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code, modified it a bit to suit to my *Test Environment* and here is the execution results:

- Code Block:

  - *multiprocess.py*:

    ```
    import time
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from multiprocessingPool.scrape import run_scrape

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        start_time = time.time()
        links = ["https://selenium.dev/downloads/", "https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/"] 
        pool = Pool(2)
        results = pool.map(run_scrape, links)
        pool.close()
        print("Total Time Processed: "+"--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    ```
  - *scrape.py*:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    def run_scrape(link):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36")
        chrome_options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
        browser.get(link)
        try:
            print(browser.title)
        except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
            print("Error")
        browser.quit()
    ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Downloads
  The Selenium Browser Automation Project :: Documentation for Selenium
  Total Time Processed: --- 10.248600006103516 seconds ---
  ```

---

### Conclusion

It is pretty much evident your program is logically flawless and just perfect.

---

### This usecase

As you mentioned this error surfaces after several hours of scraping, I suspect this due to the fact that [WebDriver is not thread-safe](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe). Having said that, if you can serialize access to the underlying driver instance, you can share a reference in more than one thread. This is not advisable. But you can always instantiate one [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance for each thread.

Ideally the issue of **thread-safety** isn't in your code but in the actual browser bindings. They all assume there will only be one command at a time (e.g. like a real user). But on the other hand you can always instantiate one *WebDriver* instance for each thread which will launch multiple browsing tabs/windows. Till this point it seems your program is perfect.

Now, different *threads* can be run on same *Webdriver*, but then the results of the tests would not be what you expect. The reason behind is, when you use multi-threading to run different tests on different tabs/windows a little bit of thread safety coding is required or else the actions you will perform like `click()` or `send_keys()` will go to the opened tab/window that is currently having the **focus** regardless of the *thread* you expect to be running. Which essentially means all the test will run simultaneously on the same tab/window that has **focus** but **not** on the intended tab/window.

Comment: would it be the processing of my scraping affects if i share only one webdriver instance? and different workers with focus in each window?

Comment: @BenjiePerez The bottom line is webdriver is not thread-safe. Now it all depends on you which measures are you going to take and how are you implementing them to serialize the access to the underlying webdriver instance.

Comment: i see thanks for the information about the behavior of webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Right now im using this threading module to instantiate one Webdriver each thread

```
import threading
threadLocal = threading.local()

def get_driver():
    browser = getattr(threadLocal, 'browser', None)
    if browser is None:
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36")
        chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
        setattr(threadLocal, 'browser', browser)
    return browser
```

and it really helps me to scrape faster than executing one driver at a time.

Comment: my question to this is how would i exit this instantiate webdriver after pool.close()? because it remains sleeping in my server after the usage of my workers.