# Python Selenium with multiprocessing causing runaway memory in chrome.exe processes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-multiprocessing

I was hoping someone could take a look at my code and explain to me why I am seeing a runaway memory issue in chrome.exe processes. When I run the program everything seems stable for a few hours, but after around 8 hours I will have a single chrome.exe process that consumes around 5Gb of memory. The application is fairly simple. for each item that I want to search, a new process is created. Inside that process I create a single driver instance and then search for an element. If the element isn't present then I refresh the driver and continue searching. Here is a generic sample of my code.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
import datetime as dt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.common.exceptions as SE
import sendMail


class itemSearch(Process):
    def __init__(self, item):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.item = item
        print("Starting Search for: "+str(self.item))
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        """For some reason multiprocessing was not allowing me to put the driver initializations outside of the run function. In threading I was able to pass the driver to init. Kept getting a PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied. Putting the driver initialization into the run function seems to have fixed this issue. No fucking clue."""
        options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=20)
        self.session = self.driver.session_id
        self.driver.get(self.item)
        #self.done = False

        while not self.done:
            self.search()
        self.driver.close()

    def search(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print("Scanning for: "+str(self.item))
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[some xpath to a button]').click()
                print("sending email")
                url = self.driver.current_url
                sendMail.sendNotification(receiver_email="yourmail.com", url=url)
                break
            except SE.NoSuchElementException:
                    print("Refreshing")
                    self.driver.refresh()
                    print(dt.datetime.now())
                    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[some other xpath]')))
        self.done = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url1 = "https://www.somesite.com"
    url2= "https://www.someothersite.com
    searchItems = [url1, url2]
    print("Starting search")
    for item in searchItems:
        print(item)
        itemSearch(item)
```

As a work-around I added a function that check memory usage for all chrome.exe processes. The check is run on each loop iteration. I have set a max memory limit and once that limit is reached I close the chrome driver and make a call to the run function again. This is actually working very well for me. Here's the new code with the function incorporated:

```
import time
import psutil
from multiprocessing import Process
import datetime as dt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.common.exceptions as SE
import sendMail


class itemSearch(Process):
    def __init__(self, item):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.item = item
        print("Starting Search for: "+str(self.item))
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """For some reason multiprocessing was not allowing me to put the driver initializations outside of the run function. In threading I was able to pass the driver to init. Kept getting a PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied. Putting the driver initialization into the run function seems to have fixed this issue. No fucking clue."""
        options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=20)
        self.session = self.driver.session_id
        self.driver.get(self.item)
        #self.done = False

        while not self.done:
            self.search()
        self.driver.close()

    def getMemoryUsage(self):
        "Return the MB of ram being used by chrome."
        process_list = []
        total_mem = 0
        for p in psutil.process_iter(['name']):
            if p.info['name'] == "chrome.exe":
                process_list.append(p.pid)

        #Calculate total memory usage
        for pid in process_list:
            try:
                #logger.info(str(pid)+" = "+str(psutil.Process(pid).memory_info().private/1000000))
                total_mem += psutil.Process(pid).memory_info().private
            except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                #logger.info("Process "+str(pid)+" not present")
                pass
        return total_mem/1000000

    def search(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print("Scanning for: "+str(self.item))
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[some xpath to a button]').click()
                print("sending email")
                url = self.driver.current_url
                sendMail.sendNotification(receiver_email="yourmail.com", url=url)
                break
            except SE.NoSuchElementException:
                    print("Refreshing")
                    self.driver.refresh()
                    print(dt.datetime.now())
                    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[some other xpath]')))
            memUsage = self.getMemoryUsage()
            print("Current Memory Usage at: "+str(memUsage)+"MB")
            if memUsage > 7000:
                #print("Memory Usage reached " +str(memUsage) +"MB. Restarting driver")
                logger.info("Memory Usage reached " +str(memUsage) +"MB. Restarting driver")
                self.driver.quit()
                self.run()
        self.done = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url1 = "https://www.somesite.com"
    url2= "https://www.someothersite.com
    searchItems = [url1, url2]
    print("Starting search")
    for item in searchItems:
        print(item)
        itemSearch(item)
```

Comment: What is that _runaway memory issue_?

Comment: @DebanjanB The process chrome.exe continues to increase memory usage over time and will consume all memory resources if not stopped.

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181613/chrome-crashes-after-several-hours-while-multiprocessing-using-selenium-through/60184086#60184086) help you?

Comment: @DebanjanB Not too much. What I ended up doing is writing a function that checks the memory usage for all chrome.exe processes. This check is run on each loop iteration. I have set a max memory limit, and once that limit is reached I close the chrome driver and make a call to the run function again. This strategy seems to have resolved the problem.